# How to get the maximum time of gap in xarray dataset

Tags: dataset, time-series, pixel, python-xarray, date-difference

I have a xarray dataset whith 3 dimensions (lat, lon, time) for each variable. I have 720 values for lat, 1440 for lon and 13140 for the time. For each pixel I have some gaps in the time series and I am trying to know what is the maximum and the mean time of the gaps. As it's a large dataset I tried to process by year.

Output for a dataset of 1 year (named combined in the code):

```
#the dataset for 1 year:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (lat: 720, lon: 1440, time: 365)
Coordinates:
* lat             (lat) float32 89.875 89.625 89.375 89.125 88.875 88.625    ...
* lon             (lon) float32 -179.875 -179.625 -179.375 -179.125 ...
* time            (time) datetime64[ns] 1981-04-06 1981-01-18 1981-09-29 ...
Data variables:
t0              (time, lat, lon) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(365, 720, 1440), chunksize=(1, 720, 1440)>
sm              (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(365, 720, 1440), chunksize=(1, 720, 1440)>
```

I tried this code with a loop for each year:

```
# create dataset of nan to then fill it with the values
var=np.zeros((36,720,1440))*np.NaN
lat = combined.lat.values
lon = combined.lon.values
time_na = time # each year
diff_day = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={'max':    (('time','lat', 'lon'), var),'mean':    (('time','lat', 'lon'), var)},
    coords={'time': time_na, 'lat': lat, 'lon':lon})

for t,name in tqdm(enumerate(filenames)): #loop for each year
  filename_year = glob(name+'/*.nc') # read all the files for the year
  combined = xr.open_mfdataset(filename_year,concat_dim='time',autoclose =True, decode_times=True)
  combined = combined.sortby(combined['time'],ascending=True) # otherwise the time is not montonic

  # calculation pixel by pixel
  for i in range(len(combined.lat)):
    for j in range(len(combined.lon)):
        if len(combined.time.values[np.isfinite(combined.sm.values[:,i,j])])>1 : # avoid cases where it's a list of nan 
            # the idea is to make the diff of time between finite (not finite values correspond to the gap) values.
            diff_day['max'].loc[t,i,j] = np.diff(combined.time.values[np.isfinite(combined.sm.values[:,i,j])]).astype('timedelta64[D]').max()/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
            diff_day['mean'].loc[t,i,j] = np.diff(combined.time.values[np.isfinite(combined.sm.values[:,i,j])]).astype('timedelta64[D]').mean()/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

This code works but the time of the process is too long. I wondering to know if there is an easier way to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the mean number of NaN values, something as simple as `da.isnull().mean(dim='time')` will do the trick. But to get the mean and max length of continuous blocks of NaNs is a more complex algorithmic question than a simple xarray procedural question.

I'm sure there are lots of ways to do this, but the one I came up with was this:

First, construct an array the same shape as your data which simply increases along the time dimension:

```
In [10]: arange = xr.ones_like(da) * np.arange(len(da.time))
```

In the toy data I made for this, each cell's time series looks like this:

```
In [11]: arange.isel(lat=0, lon=0).plot()
```

[image: steadily increasing line]

Next, create a similar array, but with periods which hold constant for each block of NaNs:

```
In [12]: cumulative_nans = (arange.where(da.notnull()).ffill(dim='time')).fillna(0)
```

In each cell, this array has stair steps for each NaN block:

```
In [13]: cumulative_nans.isel(lat=0, lon=0).plot()
```

[image: line with slope 1 but holding constant for NaN blocks]

Now you can subtract these two to get an array where the value in each cell is a counter with the cumulative number of NaNs in that block:

```
In [14]: time_series_of_cumulative_nan_blocks = (arange - cumulative_nans)
```

In each cell:

```
In [15]: time_series_of_cumulative_nan_blocks.isel(lat=0, lon=0).plot()
```

[image: increasing for each NaN block, back to 0 for each non-NaN value]

You can compute the max on this very easily:

```
In [16]: max_nan_duration = time_series_of_cumulative_nan_blocks.max(dim='time')
```

The mean is tougher. We can use the change from one time step to the next to filter the data to only include points where the next cell declines, e.g., where we have a peak:

```
In [17]: nan_block_length_peaks_only = (
    time_series_of_cumulative_nan_blocks
    .where(
        time_series_of_cumulative_nan_blocks
        .diff(dim='time', label='lower')
        < 0)
```

In each cell, this is limiting the third figure to a set of points:

```
In [18]: nan_block_length_peaks_only.isel(lat=0, lon=0).plot(marker='.')
```

[image: scatter_of_NaN_durations]

This value can be averaged to find the mean duration:

```
In [19]: mean_nan_duration = nan_block_length_peaks_only.mean(dim='time')
```

This should have significant performance benefits over looping through each cell and time period in the dataset, mostly because it relies on compiled, vectorized xarray functions rather than python loops. This computation could also be done across your entire dataset using [dask](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html), which could result in further gains, depending on your setup.